# Annotate deletes previous formatting in plt

Tags: python, matplotlib, visualization

I want to have one output but I have two and when I try to put some percentage in the diagram it puts it in the old Barchart neglecting the changes-formats that I implemented on the previous one. This is being done after the annotate function and when I press show,it includes the percentages but in the old barchart

Why plt does not save my previous changes eg the changed I did in labels and legend etc.

I know how to solve it using the Artist layer which is preferred by all developers. However I really want to figure out why plt puts the percentages in the old barchart and not in the one that i have done the changes.

```
import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
colors_list = ['#5cb85c','#5bc0de','#d9534f']
df_ds_per.div(df_ds_per.sum(1), axis=0)).plot(kind='bar',figsize=(15,4),width = 0.8,color = colors_list,edgecolor=None)
df_ds_per.plot(kind="bar",figsize=(20, 8),width=0.8,color = colors_list,edgecolor=None)  

plt.xticks(fontsize=14)
plt.yticks([])

#Remove the axes
for spine in plt.gca().spines.values():             
    spine.set_visible(False)

plt.legend(labels=df_ds_per.columns,fontsize= 14)
plt.title("Percentage of Respondents' Interest in Data Science 
Areas",fontsize= 16)

#Add the percentages
for p in df_ds_per.plot(kind="bar",figsize=(20, 8),width=0.8,color = 
colors_list,edgecolor=None).patches:
    width, height = p.get_width(), p.get_height()
    x, y = p.get_xy() 
    plt.annotate('{:.0%}'.format(height), (x, y + height + 0.01)) 


plt.show()
```

Comment: How are you initializing `df_ds_per`? I try to run your code but get `NameError: name 'df_ds_per' is not defined`.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56139715/annotate-deleted-my-previous-formatting-in-plt see my complete question here where i include the dataframe so you can run the program.Thanks for your answer JL